# Finding How Many Roots $2z^4-3z^3+3z^2-z+1=0$ has in the First Quadrant

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, polynomials

> I am trying to determine how many roots $$p(z)=2z^4-3z^3+3z^2-z+1=0$$ has in the first  quadrant.

My attempt:

We first note that $p(z)$ has real coefficients. Thus by the conjugate root theorem, the roots of $p(z)$ occur in complex conjugate pairs.

Next, we determine if $p(z)$ has roots on the axes.

*Case 1:* Suppose $p(z)$ has a root on the real axes, then $p(x)=2x^4-3x^3+3x^2-x+1=0$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Now by the rational root theorem, the only possible roots that $p(x)$ can have is when $x=1$. But $p(1)\neq 0$ and hence $p(z)$ cannot have a root on the real axes by contradiction.

Case 2: Suppose $p(z)$ has a root on the imaginary axes, then $p(iy)=2y^4+3iy^3-3y^2-iy+1=0$ for some $y\in\mathbb{R}$. Then, $$\Im(p(iy))=0\implies y(3y^2-1)=0.$$ But, $p(0)\neq 0$ and $p\left(\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)\neq 0$. Hence $p(z)$ does not have a root on the imaginary axes, by contradiction.

So, the roots are $a\pm ib$ and $c\pm id$ for $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a,b,c,d\neq 0$. Now the sum of the roots equals zero, which implies $a=-c$. Hence, there is only **one** root in each quadrant.

> My questions are, is my explanation of case $1$ and case $2$ correct? Also, (a very basic question) why does the sum of the roots equal zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your explanation for the case 1 is wrong. The rational root theorem is, as its name suggests, about *rational* roots. It doesn't allow you to deduce that there are no *real* roots (byt the way: in fact, there aren't). The explanation for case 2 is correct.

Also, the sum of the roots is *not* $0$; it is $-\dfrac{-3}2=\dfrac32$.

Comment: For case $1$, if I divide through by $2$ and hence made the polynomial monic, could I use the integer root theorem? I'm unsure of how it is best to show that no real roots exist (I vaguely remember a theorem concerning the factors of the constant term of a polynomial). I alternatively thought of trying to show that $p(x)\geq 0$, but this seemed too difficult. Also, I do agree that the sum of the roots is $-\frac{b}{a}=\frac{3}{2}$. But what does this tell us about the placement of the roots in the complex plane?

Comment: @JulianAngussmith, how do you imagine proving no integer roots (which follows from not having rational roots, by the way) will help you prove that there are no real roots?

Comment: The integer root theorem is about *integer* roots, right?! And since the sum of the roots is $\frac32$, if you prove that two conjugate roots have negative real part, you can deduce from that that the other two have positive real part.

Comment: @Jose Carols Santos This is why I (blindly) thought the sum of the roots was $0$, as $a+c=0\implies a=-c$ and hence if we let $a>0$, then $a+ib$ and $a-ib$ are in the first and forth quadrant respectively and similarly, $c+ib$ and $c-ib$ are in the second and third quadrant respectively. If $a+c=1.5$, we can't assume $a$ and $c$ are of different signs, right? I am a little confused.

Comment: @JulianAngussmith Yes, if $a+c=\frac32$, you can't assume that they have different signs.

Comment: @Ennar I am not sure, it seems so obvious. Perhaps if we could prove that $p(x)$ was positive definite or negative definite, but that doesn't seem very reliable if you can't factor the polynomial readily by inspection. That is why I thought of using factors of the constant term, but it seems I have forgotten some knowledge in basic real analysis. I'm open to suggestions

Comment: @José Carlos Santos If $w_1=a\pm ib$ and $w_2=c\pm id$, how can we determine that $\Re(w_1)=-\Re(w_2)$?

Comment: @JulianAngussmith, how could it seem obvious? It's like saying: it could be $1,2$ or $3$. It's not $1$, therefore it's not $2$ nor $3$. (Actually, what you are trying is much worse.)

Comment: @JulianAngussmith We can't.

Comment: @Ennar Do you know how to show that $p(z)$ has no real roots?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos Then how can we deduce the answer....

Comment: @JulianAngussmith Did I or did I not answer your original question?

Comment: Indeed you did. I shall put up another post asking for a solution showing that there are no real roots of $p(z)$. Or shall I edit this question? Unsure of the correct protocol for MSE.

Comment: @JulianAngussmith If you think that I've answered your question, then you should mark my answer as the accepted one. If you have some *other* question, then post it as such.

Comment: @user376343 Thanks. This post was helpful. I understand how the sum of the roots where calculated and the difference in the rational/integer root theorems. I still require further help in showing $p(z)$ has a single root in the first quadrant, but this will be asked in following posts.